# Awk - Extract and delimit and group by data in a specific column(s) from a comma delimited file

Tags: awk

I know that there are multiple posting on extracting but what I am doing is extracting specific columns from a CSV delimited files grouping by and summing two fields. I want to add an additional `DATE` column in the group but that column is `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS` and I need to extract just the date for the group by.

Example Input:

```
Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4,Column5,Column6,Column7,Column8,Column9,Column10
1/1/2016 9:05:01,O1234,APPLE,10,1.01,AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE
1/1/2016 10:05:01,O1234,APPLE,5,0.99,AAAA,BBBB,CCCC,DDDD,EEEE
```

My code:

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
   (NR!=1) {
       a[$2","$3","$9","$10]+=$4;
       b[$2","$3","$9","$10]+=$5;
       c[$2","$3","$9","$10]+=($4*$5)
   }
   END {
       for(i in a){print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}
   }
' data.txt >aa.txt
```

I need to edit this statement so that I can group on the date only 1/1/2016 for $1 vs the entire string.

```
awk -F',' -v OFS=',' '
    (NR!=1) {
        a[$1","$2","$3","$9","$10]+=$4;
        b[$1","$2","$3","$9","$10]+=$5;
        c[$1","$2","$3","$9","$10]+=($4*$5)
    }
    END {
        for(i in a){print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}
    }
' data.txt >aa.txt
```

Expected Output:

```
1/1/2016,O1234,AAPL,DDDD,EEEE,15,2.00,15.05
```

Comment: Thank you for helping me format the code.  I just edited my question to include the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="," }
NR>1 {
    sub(/ .*/,"",$1)
    k = $1 FS $2 FS $3 FS $9 FS $10
    a[k] += $4
    b[k] += $5
    c[k] += ($4*$5)
}
END {
    for (k in a) {
        print k, a[k], b[k], c[k]
    }
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
1/1/2016,O1234,APPLE,DDDD,EEEE,15,2,15.05
```

Comment: Thank you, so much more cleaner.